# Laravel 5 + Angular Js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5, asp.net-web-api

I've got a question - quite new to laravel (ver 5) combining it with AngularJs (1.3~~), using JTW auth system for token auth however I've got a question to more expierienced people: "backend" login system shall goes clean via angular ( so my whole app is included at start!?) or with a sandart page reload, should I seperate backend and frontend with diffrent dirs and "angular aps" ??

cheers Lukas

Comment: Are you looking for a way to structure your application? Folder structure ?

Comment: pretty much I am looking a logical way to build a "cms" with admin section with regular website + laravel as an API, not sure how to structure it, shall the angularJs files be seperate for admin and website itself or combined so literally everyone can inspect them which seems not to be a good idea ? I am looking for safe and proper solution.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are main concern is admin section and you are looking for where to keep angular script?